# (Reopened) What's the justification for closing this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[When answering "what are your top 3 strengths" are they looking for transferable skills or technical skills?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/181703/when-answering-what-are-your-top-3-strengths-are-they-looking-for-transferable)

It can easily be treated as a generalized question and answered in ways that work for any job opening.

It makes no sense to me that it was Closed.

Comment: Well... you know how it goes, some folks close things fast... only they know the justification they had in mind at the moment. I also agree it's on-topic, 2 votes already so I'll hammer it open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that it's answerable (it already has good answers IMHO).

I saw that it already had 2 reopen votes, so I proceeded to reopen it.